# enforcing order of calling function in google mock

Tags: c++11, googletest

I am learning about using google mock. I have observed following code as sample to specify the order of function calls. Here we are using `InSequence` object but not used any where in code. Request to guide me what idea of C++ technique is used internally by TEST_F to use this object  and enforce the oder

```
TEST_F(APlaceDescriptionService, MakesHttpRequestToObtainAddress) {
InSequence forceExpectationOrder;
HttpStub httpStub;
string urlStart{
"http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse?format=json&"};
auto expectedURL = urlStart +
"lat=" + APlaceDescriptionService::ValidLatitude + "&" +
"lon=" + APlaceDescriptionService::ValidLongitude;
EXPECT_CALL(httpStub, initialize());
EXPECT_CALL(httpStub, get(expectedURL));
PlaceDescriptionService service{&httpStub};
service.summaryDescription(ValidLatitude, ValidLongitude);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is simple: if `HttpStub::get` is called before `HttpStub::initialize`, then fail the test `APlaceDescriptionService.MakesHttpRequestToObtainAddress`. In other words, the test insures that `HttpStub::get` is not called before `httpStub` is initialized.

If your question is how it works:

`InSequence forceExpectationOrder` sets `new Sequence` object to the global `g_gmock_implicit_sequence` on creation, that uses a chain of expectations in the order of their creations.

```
// Points to the implicit sequence introduced by a living InSequence
// object (if any) in the current thread or NULL.
GTEST_API_ ThreadLocal<Sequence*> g_gmock_implicit_sequence;
```

```
// Creates the implicit sequence if there isn't one.
InSequence::InSequence() {
  if (internal::g_gmock_implicit_sequence.get() == nullptr) {
    internal::g_gmock_implicit_sequence.set(new Sequence);
    sequence_created_ = true;
  }
  // ...
}

// Deletes the implicit sequence if it was created by the constructor
// of this object.
InSequence::~InSequence() {
  if (sequence_created_) {
    delete internal::g_gmock_implicit_sequence.get();
    internal::g_gmock_implicit_sequence.set(nullptr);
  }
}
```

```
// Adds and returns an expectation spec for this mock function.
TypedExpectation<F>& AddNewExpectation(const char* file, int line,
                                       const std::string& source_text,
                                       const ArgumentMatcherTuple& m) {
  // ...

  // Adds this expectation into the implicit sequence if there is one.
  Sequence* const implicit_sequence = g_gmock_implicit_sequence.get();
  if (implicit_sequence != nullptr) {
    implicit_sequence->AddExpectation(Expectation(untyped_expectation));
  }

  return *expectation;
}
```